# Caliper bolts after crash: repair or replace?

Tags: brakes, repair

A few days ago, I was looking down checking out my crank while riding and drifted into the LA River Bike Path and ended up crashing bending my front brake caliper.  Can the recessed bolt that holds the brake caliper in place be bent back straight or should I just buy a new one?

Comment: Unless you can't find the bolt, replace it.

Comment: (I'm betting it's a common replacement part and any bike shop should carry it.)

Answer (score 7):

My vote is for replacement. It does after all hold on the brake a very important component. Bending the bolt may cause microscopic cracks that could cause the bolt to fail with no warning.

Comment: Plus, if you can find just a bolt, it should be a very cheap fix.  If you can't get one new, you can probably salvage one off an old bike if you have a used bike shop or bike dump in your area.

Comment: You don't want to take chances with front brake as it provides more than three quarters of stopping power.

Comment: Yes, replace it especially if the bolt is an aluminium one because bending aluminium only weakens it. In addition, a failing bolt when front braking will be very dangerous not because you'll not have a front brake but because most probably this will send you OTB (over the bars) when the caliper will be ejected forward but then unable to be untangled from the front wheel (if you have a fatter tyre than your rims) will force the front wheel to a sudden stop.